# How to open an Internet tab in the Microsoft Bot framework server side?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I need to open a url tab when the user clicks an action.submit on an adaptive card.  I do not want to user Action.OpenURL. In the OnEvent method, i would like to add some code to open a internet tab on the client side. Is it possible to open a tab in the client side (MICROSOFT TEAMS) from the server side within the Microsoft Bot framework? If yes, how could i do it in C#.

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: Microsoft teams

Comment: ok. sorry can't help you then

Comment: @Justin - Are you saying you want to perform a double action by sending an activity to the bot and opening a URL on the client side simultaneously? If that's the case, you're going in the wrong direction by using a submit action and then trying to have the bot open a URL on the client side. The correct route is to use an open-URL action and then have the URL access the bot before redirecting to the desired page. Example: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/OpenUrlRedirectBot (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: Thanks @KyleDelaney

Comment: @Justin - That didn't answer my question

Comment: Sorry Kyle. Thats what I did, my goal was to log an event when the user opens the card. I have use the Redirect solution. We send adaptive cards to the user via another service and in the adaptive card json we add the scheme and host value to the url. We added the RedirectController to the botframework solution

Answer (score 1):

It is common to want to combine a submit action and an open-URL action in one button, so that the bot receives an activity when the user opens a page. Since no cards support double actions, there are a few ideas to explore when trying to get this to work:

1. Use a submit action and then have the bot send an activity back to the channel that makes a page open automatically
2. Use an open-URL action and then have the URL access the bot

The first idea is impossible unless you're using Web Chat because there aren't any activities that make a client open a URL, and if you're using Web Chat then you might as well extend it to support double actions.

For the second idea, there are a few ways to go about it. You could host a separate API that sends an activity to the bot or you could have the URL be in the bot's own domain and have it call the bot code directly. In any case, once the bot is notified about the action you'll want the user to be redirected to the actual page you want them to see. There's an example of that here: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/OpenUrlRedirectBot

Comment: Is this sample available for SDK3 c#?